# How can convert a string into an argument name and pass it to a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments

So I have this function

```
def f(a=1, b=1):
    print("a:", a, "| b:", b)
```

and this dictionary `args = {"a": 4, "b": 5}`. What I want is to make a loop to call `f(a=4)` in the first iteration and `f(b=5)` in the second. So basically something like this

```
for key,value in args.items():
    f(key=value)
```

but somehow making `key` an argument instead of a string. The output should be:

```
a: 4 | b: 1
a: 1 | b: 5
```

but of course I'm getting `TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I think you are looking for both of the uses of `**` for keyword arguments.

```
def f(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        f(**{k: v})
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! That's what I was looking for :). `**` has always confused me... I guess it's time I do some serious reading about it.